# First differences panel data depending on extra variables R

Tags: r, plm

I have a panel dataset which looks like the following

```
ID     Model    Month    Country      Activations  avg_price
1      VW Golf  2012-01  NL              23           5000
1      VW Golf  2012-02  NL              2            5500
1      VW Golf  2012-01  FR              8            6000
1      VW Golf  2012-02  FR              34           7000
2      Audi TT  2012-01  NL              8            6900
```

Now, I want to take first differences for the `Activations` and `avg_price` variables. I do this using the `diff(data$Activations)` function from the `plm` package, but first I have to transform the data frame using `pdata.frame(data)`. So:

```
data_fd = pdata.frame(data)
data_fd$Activations = diff(data_fdactivations)
```

This returns the following error using the data above: `duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame`. This is because I have data on different countries and when I aggregate the data over all the countries (so total `Activations` and `avg_price` and only one id-month combination) this works fine. However, I want now to take the first differences also using the `Country` variable.

My dataframe should, then, look like:

```
 ID     Model    Month    Country      Activations  avg_price
 1      VW Golf  2012-01  NL              NA           NA
 1      VW Golf  2012-02  NL             -21           500
 1      VW Golf  2012-01  FR              NA           NA
 1      VW Golf  2012-02  FR              26           1000
 etc
```

Does anyone know how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look ,is this what you want?

```
lag_new <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Model = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Audi TT", "VW Golf"), class = "factor"), 
                          Month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2012-01", 
                                                                              "2012-02"), class = "factor"), Country = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                   2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("FR", "NL"), class = "factor"), 
                          Activations = c(23L, 2L, 8L, 34L, 8L), avg_price = c(5000L, 
                                                                               5500L, 6000L, 7000L, 6900L), Activations_new = c(NA, -21L, 
                                                                                                                                6L, 26L, -26L), avg_price_new = c(NA, 500L, 500L, 1000L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -100L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

lag_new$Activations_new <- lag_new$Activations-lag(lag_new$Activations)
lag_new$avg_price_new <- lag_new$avg_price-lag(lag_new$avg_price)
```

Comment: Using this approach the `lag_new$Activations` and `lag(lag_new$Activations)` are equal and therefore I get only zeros

Comment: i am not getting any zero in this approach